# How to calculate the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \int\limits_0^1 \frac{n(2nx^{n-1}-(1+x))}{2(1+x)}\,dx$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

How to calculate the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{n(2nx^{n-1}-(1+x))}{2(1+x)} dx$?

I have to calculate the limit when solving

> Find $a,b$ for $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{n-1}}{x+1} dx=\dfrac{a}{n}+\dfrac{b}{n^2}+o(\dfrac{1}{n^2}) (n\to\infty)$

First I calculated that

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \displaystyle\int_0^1 \dfrac{nx^{n-1}}{x+1} dx=\dfrac{1}{2}$, thus $a=\dfrac{1}{2}$, then 
$2b=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_0^1\dfrac{n(2nx^{n-1}-(1+x))}{2(1+x)} dx$.

However, I cannot find a good way to calculate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align*}
2b &= \lim_n n \int_0^1 \frac{nx^{n-1}} {x+1} \mathrm dx - \frac n 2 \\
&= \lim_n n \int_0^1 \frac {\mathrm d (x^n)} {x+1} - \frac n2\\
&= \lim_n n \left. \frac {x^n} {1+x}\right|_0^1 + n \int_0^1 \frac {x^n \mathrm dx} {(1+x)^2} - \frac n 2\\
&= \lim_n \frac n {n+1} \cdot \left.\frac {x^{n+1}}{(x+1)^2}\right|_0^1 + \frac {2n}{n+1}\int_0^1 \frac {x^{n+1}}{(x+1)^3} \mathrm d x\\
&= \frac 14 + 2\lim_n \int_0^1 \frac {x^{n+1} \mathrm dx} {(x+1)^3}\\
&= \frac 14,
\end{align*}
where
$$
0 \gets \frac 18 \int_0^1 x^{n+1} \mathrm dx \leqslant \int_0^1 \frac {x^{n+1} \mathrm dx} {(1+x)^3} \leqslant \int_0^1 x^{n+1} \mathrm d x \to 0. 
$$

UPDATE

The limit you gave at the very first is actually $b$, not $2b$.

Comment: Falling behind again... Hmm

Answer (score 1):

Your evaluation of $a$ is correct. As regards $b$, note that, by integration by parts applied twice, we have that
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{n-1}}{x+1} dx&=\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n}}{(x+1)^2} dx
\\
&=\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{4n(n+1)}+\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+1}}{(x+1)^3} dx.\end{align}$$
Morever
$$0\leq \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+1}}{(x+1)^3} dx\leq \int_0^1 x^{n+1}dx=\frac{1}{n+2}.$$
Hence
$$\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{n-1}}{x+1} dx=\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{4n^2}+O(1/n^3)$$
and it follows that $b=1/4$ (and $a=1/2$).

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n - 1} \over x + 1}\,\dd x =
> {a \over n} + {b \over n^{2}} + \mrm{o}\pars{1 \over n^{2}}}$
>   as $\ds{n \to \infty:\ {\Large ?}}$.

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n - 1} \over x + 1}\,\dd x}} =
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n - 1} - x^{n} \over 1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n/2 - 1} - x^{n/2 - 1/2} \over
1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\bracks{%
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n/2 - 1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{n/2 - 1} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] = &\
{1 \over 2}\bracks{\Psi\pars{{n \over 2} + {1 \over 2}} -
\Psi\pars{n \over 2}}\quad\pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

As $\ds{n \to \infty}$:
\begin{equation}
\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\Psi\pars{{n \over 2} + {1 \over 2}}} & \ds{\sim} &
\ds{\ln\pars{n \over 2} + {1 \over 24\pars{n/2}^{2}} -
{7 \over 960\pars{n/2}^{4}} + \cdots}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\Psi\pars{n \over 2}} & \ds{\sim} &
\ds{\ln\pars{n \over 2} - {1 \over 2\pars{n/2}} - {1 \over 12\pars{n/2}^{2}} +
{1 \over 120\pars{n/2}^{4}} + \cdots}
\end{array}\right.\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

> \eqref{1} and \eqref{2} lead to

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n - 1} \over x + 1}\,\dd x}} \sim {\color{red}{1/2} \over n} + {\color{red}{1/4} \over n^{2}} +
\mrm{o}\pars{1 \over n^{4}}
\\[5mm] &\ \implies
\bbx{a = {1 \over 2}\,,\quad b = {1 \over 4}}
\end{align}

---

**ANOTHER METHOD**: The
[Laplace one](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method). Namely,

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n - 1} \over x + 1}\,\dd x}} =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\pars{1 - x}^{n - 1} \over 1 - x/2}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{1}{\expo{\pars{n- 1}\ln\pars{1 - x}} \over 1 - x/2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\expo{-\pars{n - 1}x}\expo{-\pars{n - 1}x^{2}/2} \over 1 - x/2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{\mrm{as}\ n\ \to\ \infty}{\sim}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\pars{n - 1}x}
\bracks{1 + {x \over 2} + \pars{{3 \over 4} - {n \over 2}}\,x^{2}}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 2}\,{4n^{2} - 10n + 8 \over 4\pars{n - 1}^{3}}
\\[5mm] & \sim
\bbx{{\color{red}{1/2} \over n} + {\color{red}{1/4} \over n^{2}}} + \cdots
\end{align}